Nuget JFROG connection failed "Unable to load the service index for source"
Jenkins pipeline fails:
Determining projects to restore...

[2024-09-10T10:33:55.379Z]   Restored /mnt/jenkins/workspace/e_Interaction_Engine_release_1.3/src/Core/name.CorePlatform.GameInteractionEngine.Common/name.CorePlatform.GameInteractionEngine.Common.csproj (in 96 ms).

[2024-09-10T10:33:55.379Z]   Restored /mnt/jenkins/workspace/e_Interaction_Engine_release_1.3/src/Core/name.CorePlatform.GameInteractionEngine.Domain/name.CorePlatform.GameInteractionEngine.Domain.csproj (in 98 ms).

[2024-09-10T10:33:55.380Z] /mnt/jenkins/workspace/e_Interaction_Engine_release_1.3/src/Core/name.CorePlatform.GameInteractionEngine.Services/name.CorePlatform.GameInteractionEngine.Application.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://name.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/core-nuget/index.json. [/mnt/jenkins/workspace/e_Interaction_Engine_release_1.3/CorePlatformGameInteractionEngine.sln]

This is running on server, not in VS code.
There is no NuGet proxy settings, because that has been working with this ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.config 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  <add key="private-feed" value="https://name.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/core-nuget/index.json" />
</packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <private-feed>
        <add key="Username" value="username" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="passwd" />
      </private-feed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>

I reused jfrog set me up function, but isn't helping.
In the image you can see nuget sources. Before I reused jfrog set me up, there was third private-feed above artifactory and public nuget, I deleted it and don't know what was written there.
enter image description here
